# Android - OutOfMemoryError crash

Tags: java, android, multithreading

Recently started getting this exception on firebase. I was unable to understand what could be the reason behind this crash. Little help will be appreciated. Thanks in Advance.

**Based on Android 7 only.**

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
Failed to allocate a 28 byte allocation with 3992 free bytes and 3KB until OOM
```

> ```
> Fatal Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 28 byte allocation with 3992 free bytes and 3KB until OOM
>        at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.addConditionWaiter(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1850)
>        at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2068)
>        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1103)
>        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1084)
>        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1058)
>        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1118)
>        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
>        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:762)
> ```

Comment: Start here: https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/memory-profiler

Comment: @StephenC ok , let me look into it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many reasons for that issue, such as: Draw large bitmap, or leak memory.
In that case, at first - you should check & fix leak memory for your app by 'Leak Canary', or  Android Studio Profiler

Comment: can you share an example link?

Comment: you can follow below links:
https://square.github.io/leakcanary/fundamentals-fixing-a-memory-leak/ 
https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/memory-profiler
(leak canary maybe a little easier for newer)